# Adding custom column to regression table (tab_model, sjplot)?

Tags: r, regression

I'd like to add my own column containing VIF values to a regression table that I've made with the `tab_model()` function in the `sjplot` package.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
log_fit <- glm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)
require(sjplot)
tab <- tab_model(log_fit)
require(car)
VIF_vals <- vif(log_fit)
```

I'd like to add the `VIF_vals$GVIF` data as a column to the `tab` object, with each VIF value in the row corresponding to the same IV (e.g. Sepal Width, Petal Length, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this can be done with a different function and package: `summ()` function in the `jtools` package by setting `vifs = TRUE`.

However, I'd still prefer to use the `tab_model()` function instead since it has the appropriate R-squared value I want (Tjur), makes the confidence intervals look nicer, and has the option of including the deviance.